Copilot inline chat icon shifts the whole body of the codefile to the right. How do I prevent the shift?
Every time Copilot inline chat icon shows up in Rider, the whole body of my file moves to the right. To say that it is infuriating is to say nothing. Please help me make sure tthe body of my codefile remains  exactly where it is at all times.
I need the Copilot, so an ideal solution will keep it working but prevent the shift.

